# Custom query to show posts

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to sort posts based on rating (using wp-postrating plugin) and numbers of comments. I have made this using wpdb, but i kinda wish to make it easier and use it with wp_query. Seems that I can not find any way to achieve this because I do not know any method to orderby two items in $args.

My wpdb code looks like this...

`$wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value, id, post_title, comment_count FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id
WHERE post_type='post'
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='ratings_average'
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC, comment_count DESC");`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `wp_query`

```
$args = array(  'post_type'     => 'post',
                'numberposts'   => -1,
                'posts_per_page'=> -1,
                'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
                'meta_key'      => 'ratings_average',
                'order'         => 'DESC',
            );
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Now the result is `DESC Order`.

Comment: Yes, but I also need to sort it DESC by comments number.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer doesn't solve Iulians problem. You just showed how to order posts by meta_value. Am I missing something?

Comment: sorry i didnt read the full problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use multiple fields in `orderby` argument. Codex [shows you](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) how to do it:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'title menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

And it should solve your problem. (It should, but if you want to sort DESC it probably won't, because of this WordPress bug: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17065)

Of course you always can use [`posts_orderby`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) filter to create your own `ORDER BY` part of query.

```
function my_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    $orderby_statement = "YOUR ORDER BY STATEMENT";
    return $orderby_statement;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'my_posts_orderby');
```

Just add this filter just before you call your query and remove it after.

Comment: If I use this: `$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'ratings_average',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value comment_count',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);` it works somehow. But it`s not filtering right.

Comment: What do you mean by "not filtering right"? You can always look at SQL query that was generated by wp_query (just var_dump wp_query object).

Comment: For example I have a post with 5 average rating, 0 comments. I have one with 4 average rating and 3 comments, and I have another one with 5 average and 2 comments. By using that exact code the order is just as I wrote it...should be 1 3 2.

Comment: What SQL does this wp_query generate?

Comment: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'ratings_average' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value,wp_posts.comment_count DESC LIMIT 0, 5)`

Comment: Here`s a fun fact. If I sort ASC instead of DESC the order is right. Just that when it shows the posts, starts with those with 0 comments and 0 ratings, continuing in the right order...

Comment: Well, I guess this SQL query is missing DESC after first field to order by. I looked at wp_query source code and I don't see any way to change it, so you will have to use my second solution (posts_orderby filter).

Comment: There is even a ticket for this in WPs track: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24133 and http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17065